# How to reproduce the Mathematica solution for $\int(\cos x)^{\frac23}dx$?

Tags: integration, special-functions, indefinite-integrals

I entered this integration problem to Mathematica Online Integrator an got a solution I would never have been able to find manually.

$$\int\root 3 \of{\cos(x)^2}\,dx=\frac{(-3\cos(x)\root 3 \of{\cos(x)^2}*Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 5/6, 11/6, \cos(x)^2]*\sin(x))}{5\sqrt{\sin(x)^2}}$$

I would like to see/learn how the trick works to solve/reproduce this the manual way.

Comment: It's really ugly answer to me.

Comment: Use the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) and then switch the order of summation and integration.

Comment: I also was disappointed that such a "nice" integral results in such an "ugly" answer.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding the above comment, we can write (say, for $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$)
\begin{align}
\int \cos^{r}x\,dx&=-\int \cos^r x\left(1-\cos^2 x\right)^{-\frac12}\,d(\cos x)=\\
&=-\int \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(k+\frac12)}{k!\,\Gamma(\frac12)}\cos^{r+2k}x\,d(\cos x)=\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(k+\frac12)}{k!\,\Gamma(\frac12)}\frac{\cos^{r+1+2k}x}{r+1+2k}=\\
&=-\frac{\cos^{r+1}x}{r+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac12)_k(\frac{r+1}{2})_k}{k!\,(\frac{r+3}{2})_k}\left(\cos^2 x\right)^k=\\
&=-\frac{\cos^{r+1}x}{r+1}{}_2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac{r+1}{2};\frac{r+3}{2};\cos^2 x\right),\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $(a)_k=\frac{\Gamma(a+k)}{\Gamma(a)}$ denotes the Pochhammer symbol.
It remains to  set $r=\frac23$ in the last formula.

Comment: Thats exactly the answer I was looking for. The mystery of solution is now solved. I have a copyright-oriented question : is it allowed to use this result/way of solution in an own perhaps copyright-protected script publishing of course the source and author ?

Comment: Please feel free to use this without any referencing.

Comment: If I set $r=0$ in the above equation there results a funny formula.

Comment: I noticed the following. $$\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{\frac \pi 2} \root 3 \of{\cos^2(x)}\,dx$$ is greater zero. But if I try to calculate with the solution given I get zero ( I used WolframAlpha ). This seems not to be an error using the CAS as $$\cos(x)=0$$ for $$\pm \frac \pi 2$$.

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann Good point. The seeming contradiction is related to that for $x\in(-\pi/2,0)$ we should replace (at the very first step) $\sin x$ by $-\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ (i.e. there is a sign difference). If you want to have an antiderivative valid for $ x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, in addition to modifying the sign one should add a constant to one of the two expressions ensuring that they match at $x=0$.

Comment: How can the integral formula $$\int\frac{1}{\root n\of{cos^{n-1}(nx)}}\, dx$$ be proved according to the  way gone above ? CAS shows also in this case a similar solution using again the hypergeometric function of Gauss. As far as I guess the solution is of the form $$-\frac{\cos(nx)}{\root n \of{\cos^{n-1}(nx)}}{}_2F_1(\frac{1}{2n},\frac 12;\frac{2n+1}{2n};\cos^2(nx))$$

Comment: Of course simply $r=\frac{n-1}{n}$.